AWS Java CDK Kinesis/Glue format conversion
I'm playing around with the alpha (yeah, I know) CDK support for Kinesis Firehose S3 destinations and Glue tables, trying to get conversion to Parquet format
The javadoc mentions that conversion is a type of S3Bucket.processor but there is no current implementation, what would be the correct way of escape hatching so you could set serializer and glue information for the conversion?
Thanks in advance,
Nik

There is an implementation - LambdaDataProcessor: https://constructs.dev/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha/v/2.151.0-alpha.0/api/LambdaFunctionProcessor?lang=java

Thanks for the tip. I wrote a lambda for setting the partitionKeys in the metdata but now the delivery stream cries
"Dynamic Partitioning Namespaces can only be part of a prefix exp
ression when Dynamic Partitioning is enabled"
but I see no enable for that in the S3Bucket or DestinationStream builder. I sort of though it would be implicitly set when using .processor(lambda). Escape hatch here?
Thanks in advance,

That is probably a separate question
